# how to make firebase infinite loop showing the result

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi3

When I run this code, it stops looping with this error:

> object has no attribute 'firebaseapplication'

and only the two first values are printed.

How can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
from firebase import firebase


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            print(line)
            firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://smartcabinet-ahmed.firebaseio.com/')
            result = firebase.put("fruit","rice",line)


print(result)
```

Comment: Made it readable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're overriding the firebase variable in the while loop every time. Set the variable to be something else and you should be fine. Maybe something like this?:

```
while True:
    db = firebase.FirebaseApplication('dsn')
    # do some operation with db object
    db.put(...)
```

You could also move the firebase object initialization out of the while loop, if you don't need to reinitialize the connection every time. That would also solve your problem I believe.

```
db = firebase.FirebaseApplication('dsn')
while True:
    db.put(...)
```